# How to allow only single executed task using streams or buffering stream event while executing long operation

Tags: flutter, stream, rxdart

I have some process which can be called periodically and forcibly. The process can take some time. I need to disallow to start next `automatic task` until `forcible task` is still executing, or I need to disallow the `forcible task` until `automatic task` is still executing (i.e. only **one** active task is allowed). Yes, I understand that I can use some `_isBusy` flag to define if task is still executing and skip adding to sink. But maybe there is a more *elegant* solution using streams (rxdart)? Moreover I **would like** if events not be missed but buffered so when the active task is completed, the next event is taken from `_controller.stream`.

```
class Processor {
  bool _isBusy;
  final _controller = StreamController<int>.broadcast();

  Processor() {
    _controller.stream.listen((_) async {
      if (!_isBusy) {
        await _execTask(); // execute long task
      }
    });
  }

  void startPeriodicTask() {
    Stream.periodic(duration: Duration(seconds: 15)).listen((_) {
      _controller.sink.add(1);
    })
  }

  void execTask() {
    _controller.sink.add(1);
  }

  void _execTask() async {
    try {
      _isBusy = true;
      // doing some staff
    } finally {
      _isBusy = false;
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html maybe?

Comment: Hm... more details please (maybe small example). I understand that stream will wait for future completion (_execTask) but it seems I didn't catch the idea.

P.S. Is it possible to know how much events in stream still not processed?

Comment: basically your mapping function has to return a `Future` to signal  that your task is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experience I got I found out that each event in stream is processed one by one. So when one event is still processing the second one is waiting its turn in stream and more over `sent events are not missing`!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at [rxdart reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/), but I can't find the elegant method.

If I was to say it, you can `where`.

```dart
_controller.stream.where((_) => !_isBusy).listen((_) async {
    await _execTask();
});
```